# How to open channel with output of closing channel? [Lightning Network]

Tags: transaction-fees, lightning-network, channel-factories

How can I automatically open a new channel while closing another, avoiding to create an unnecessary intermediate transaction?
Do any wallets support it at the moment, or would I have to do it with a CLI?

Comment: For the record C-lightning could support it (`fundchannel_start` the new channel, [gather the closing transaction id], `fundchannel_complete`, `close` with the `destination` parameter) but you would have to get the transaction id manually (which isn't very practical...)